# what are the possible options and default values for CJuiAutoComplete?

Tags: yii

The documentation of CJuiAutoComplete only say:

options property
public array $options;
the initial JavaScript options that should be passed to the JUI plugin.

and i have seen minLength and select in examples, but i cant find a complet list of option and defaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the API page for [CJUIAutoComplete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete)

> Please refer to the [JUI AutoComplete API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) documentation for possible
>   options (name-value pairs) and [JUI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) page for general
>   description and demo.